# Jquery how to - asp.net textbox change updates another textbox

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i have 2 asp.net textboxes on a page. using jquery how can i update the text of the second one when the first one changes.
Has to be jquery using asp.net textboxes

e.g.  as user types 'hello' into first box the second box will automatically fill with the same text. should happen as user types and not when user leaves text box

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function SyncTextBoxes(txt)
{
    var t = $(txt).val();
    $('#<%= txtFirst.ClientID %>').val(t);
    $('#<%= txtSecond.ClientID %>').val(t);
}
```

and

```
<asp:Textbox ID="txtFirst" onkeypress="SyncTextBoxes(this)" runat="server" />
<asp:Textbox ID="txtSecond" onkeypress="SyncTextBoxes(this)" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight improvement to jelbourn's answer; best to use the onkeyup event otherwise the text will not include the last key pressed.